# How to implement foldl using foldr in Erlang?

Tags: erlang, fold

This is what I thought, any options for a better thought?

```
foldl(Function,Factor,List) -> lists:foldr(fun(X,Acc) -> Acc ++ [X] end,[],lists:foldr(Function,Factor,List)).
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to read the [Code](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/lists.erl#L1253) for stdlib of Erlang/OTP.